# How do i change the key values in a php array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Changing a nested (multidimentional) array into key => value pairs in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1081612/changing-a-nested-multidimentional-array-into-key-value-pairs-in-php)

I have this array

```
[5] => Array
        (
            [completed_system_products_id] => 1
            [completed_systems_id] => 76
            [step_number] => 1
            [product_id] => 92
            [category] => hardware
            [date_added] => 2011-05-03 13:44:01
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [completed_system_products_id] => 2
            [completed_systems_id] => 76
            [step_number] => 2
            [product_id] => 62
            [category] => hardware
            [date_added] => 2011-05-03 13:44:51
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [completed_system_products_id] => 3
            [completed_systems_id] => 76
            [step_number] => 3
            [product_id] => 104
            [category] => hardware
            [date_added] => 2011-05-03 13:44:56
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [completed_system_products_id] => 4
            [completed_systems_id] => 76
            [step_number] => 4
            [product_id] => 251
            [category] => hardware
            [date_added] => 2011-05-03 13:48:56
        )
```

How do i make the keys values the same as the [step_number] =>

so for example i want this outcome

```
    [1] => Array
        (
            [completed_system_products_id] => 1
            [completed_systems_id] => 76
            [step_number] => 1
            [product_id] => 92
            [category] => hardware
            [date_added] => 2011-05-03 13:44:01
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [completed_system_products_id] => 2
            [completed_systems_id] => 76
            [step_number] => 2
            [product_id] => 62
            [category] => hardware
            [date_added] => 2011-05-03 13:44:51
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [completed_system_products_id] => 3
            [completed_systems_id] => 76
            [step_number] => 3
            [product_id] => 104
            [category] => hardware
            [date_added] => 2011-05-03 13:44:56
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [completed_system_products_id] => 4
            [completed_systems_id] => 76
            [step_number] => 4
            [product_id] => 251
            [category] => hardware
            [date_added] => 2011-05-03 13:48:56
        )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$new = array();
foreach ($old as $value) {
    $new[$value['step_number']] = $value;
}
$old = $new;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = array(); // Create a new array to hold the result
foreach ($array as $val) { // Loop the original array
  $result[$val['step_number']] = $val; // Add the value to the new array with the correct key
}
ksort($result); // Sort the array by key
print_r($result); // Display the result
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$results = array();
foreach ($array as $item)
{
  $results[$item['step_number']] = $item;
}
```